# Flaw in ToolStripItemCollection.AddRange method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am strongly convinced that in implementation of ToolStripItemCollection.AddRange is a mistake:

I made Windows Forms Application with two menus, each one containing 2 items.

[first menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7IEy.jpg)

[second menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT45M.jpg)

(Excuse me, but I don't have enough reputation to post images).

Next, I implement button click handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    menu1.DropDownItems.AddRange(menu2.DropDownItems);
}
```

and System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was thrown.

I was extremely curious why this was happening and I decompiled ToolStripItemCollection assembly with ILSpy. Here it is what I saw:

```
public void AddRange(ToolStripItemCollection toolStripItems)
{
    if (toolStripItems == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("toolStripItems");
    }
    if (this.IsReadOnly)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(SR.GetString("ToolStripItemCollectionIsReadOnly"));
    }
    using (new LayoutTransaction(this.owner, this.owner, PropertyNames.Items))
    {
        int count = toolStripItems.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            this.Add(toolStripItems[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

There is nothing to be bothered about. Let's look into ToolStripItemCollection.Add Method:

```
public int Add(ToolStripItem value)
{
    this.CheckCanAddOrInsertItem(value);
    this.SetOwner(value);
    int result = base.InnerList.Add(value);
    if (this.itemsCollection && this.owner != null)
    {
        this.owner.OnItemAdded(new ToolStripItemEventArgs(value));
    }
    return result;
}
```

and eventually into ToolStripItemCollection.SetOwner:

```
private void SetOwner(ToolStripItem item)
{
    if (this.itemsCollection && item != null)
    {
        if (item.Owner != null)
        {
            item.Owner.Items.Remove(item);
        }
        item.SetOwner(this.owner);
        if (item.Renderer != null)
        {
            item.Renderer.InitializeItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```

We can clearly see, that for loop delete item from *toolStripItems* in every step. MSDN puts remarks about IList interface which ToolStripItemCollection implements:
**In collections of contiguous elements, such as lists, the elements that follow the removed element move up to occupy the vacated spot. If the collection is indexed, the indexes of the elements that are moved are also updated.**. 
As a result, we end up accesing item in toolStripItems on wrong index (second item shifted to position 0). Am I right?

Comment: Sure, it wasn't written to deal with your scenario.  These items already having an Owner is the failure mode.  You'll have to copy the collection so it can't be modified while it is being iterated.  Pretty common issue btw.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what the question is, but you can work around the issue by converting your collection into an array (which requires a cast):

```
menu1.DropDownItems.AddRange(menu2.DropDownItems.Cast<ToolStripItem>().ToArray());
```

Your version is throwing an error is because when the first menu gets added to the DropDown collection, it is getting removed from the collection it is iterating over, hence the OutOfRangeException.

Comment: Question is: Is this method flawed or I am missing something. I don't want to make ugly casts when I have opportunity to use appropriate method.